# Error running ruby script and use gems using ssh2 of php from remote server

Tags: php, ruby, phpseclib, ssh2-exec

I have a server on which ruby and basic gems sets like mysql2, capistrano is installed and I am trying to trigger my ruby script from a **remote server (PHP server) using SSH2**. My script is running all OK on the ruby server but when I try the same from the remote server using ssh2 I am not able to run that ruby script.

For testing I have written a simple scripts which simply prints a statement and it works on when I have to pass the absolute path where ruby is installed.

But now it is very tedious for me get path for every gem installed for my ruby script. Below is the error

```
"/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sshkit (LoadError)



"/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)
```

Below is the script which I am trying to execute on my php server

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ip');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($ssh->exec('/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby /home/user/deployment/crm/crm.rb'));
echo '</pre>';
```

If I try to run this without ruby path I am getting

```
bash ruby command not found
```

Any suggestions how can I simply execute my ruby script from a remote server.

Comment: I wonder if it'd work better with a PTY or with read() / write(): http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a failure to set up RVM correctly rather than anything else.

Check this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/413683/how-to-get-ruby-when-called-from-a-shell-script-to-see-rvm-default-ruby

Adapted from there:

```
# Assumes that 2.2.0 is already fully-installed under RVM.
rvm --default use ruby-2.2.0
```

And that would need to be run for the user you login as. You probably want to read and understand that answer to ensure that you get what you need.

It may be much simpler to just install the gems to the default ruby…